# An invariant that determines membership in an element of $Gr(2,\mathbb{C}^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, grassmannian

Consider two basis vectors for a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3,$ $v_1=(z_1,z_2,z_3),v_2=(z'_1,z'_2,z'_3)$. I am looking for a geometric or algebraic invariant that determines if another vector $v_3\in$ span$\{v_1,v_2\}$ in a generalized version of this solution for $Gr(1,\mathbb{C}^n)$: For a vector $v=(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)$, the ratios $\frac{|z_i|}{|z_j|}$ and $angle(z_i,z_j)$ (i.e. the oriented angle between components) are invariant under scalar multiples of $v$. Therefore, a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is determined by ${n \choose 2}$ values for ratios of lengths and ${n \choose 2}$ angles.

Comment: What is the definition of $Gr(m, \mathbb C^n)$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath Grassmannian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian

Answer (score 1):

From your example for the line case, I assume you don't care about redundancies. The Plücker coordinates
$$p_{ij} = \left(\det \begin{bmatrix}z_i & z_j\\ z_i' & z_j'\end{bmatrix}\right)_{1 \le i < j \le n}$$
are invariant in the sense that choosing a different basis changes them by a constant (the determinant of the $2 \times 2$ change-of-basis matrix). That is, they provide an embedding of $\operatorname{Gr}(2, \mathbb{C}^n)$ into $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^{\binom{n}{2}}) = \operatorname{Gr}(1, \mathbb{C}^{\binom{n}{2}})$. You already have a way to encode these, so you get $2\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}$ quantities $|p_{ij}/p_{kl}|$ and $\operatorname{angle}(p_{ij}, p_{kl})$.

I do have one objection with your encoding of projective space: even if you set $|z_i|/|z_j|$ to be $\infty$ when $z_j = 0$, $\operatorname{angle}(z_i, 0)$ really isn't a sensible thing to write.